# If $n > e^{1/|h|}$, then $|n^{-h} - 1| \leq 2n^{|h|}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given that $n > e^{1/|h|}$. What I really want to show is that $$ \left| \frac{n^{-h} - 1}{h} \right| \leq \frac{2n^{|h|}}{|h|}.$$ This is relatively straightforward if I know $|n^{-h} - 1| \leq 2n^{|h|}$. However, I'm being really tripped up by the fact that it's hard to say anything about $n^h$ even though we know the lower bound on $n$ because $h$ may be negative or positive (therefore changing the direction of the inequality).

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in cases. Prove it separately for $h>0$ and $h<0$.

Case 1: $h > 0$

In this case, $|h| = h$, so the assumption says that $n > e^{1/h}$. Since $h$ is positive, $n^h > e$. Taking reciprocals, we get $n^{-h} < e^{-1}$. Now finish by using the triangle inequality:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
|n^{-h} - 1| &\leq& |n^{-h}| + 1 \\
             &\leq& e^{-1} + 1 \\
             &\leq& e + e \\
             &\leq& n^h + n^h \\
             &=& 2n^{|h|}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Case 2: $h<0$

Now that $h<0$ we have $|h| = -h$, so the assumption says $n > e^{-1/h}$. Since $h$ is negative, taking the power $h$ reverses the inequality (as you pointed out), so we get $n^h < e^{-1}$. Taking reciprocals we get $n^{-h} > e$. Now just finish again by using the triangle inequality:

$$
\begin {eqnarray}
|n^{-h} - 1| &\leq& |n^{-h}| + 1 \\
             &=& n^{|h|} + 1 \\
             &\leq& n^{|h|} + e \\
             &\leq& n^{|h|} + n^{-h} \\
             &=& 2n^{|h|}
\end{eqnarray}
$$